# How to increase filter limit in Bigtable query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

I created complex filter (FilterList) that includes several subfilters. Query with that filter could not been executed because of

```
StatusRuntimeException INVALID_ARGUMENT: Row filter exceeds maximum size of 4096 bytes.
```

I checked quotas and service limitation for Cloud Bigtable:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design#size-limits
- https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/quota

There is no document that defines mentioned limit. I also checked `BigtableOptionsFactory`, but saw no option to change that limit.
How can I avoid that limit?

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.IOExceptionWithStatus: Error in response stream
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractClientScanner$1.hasNext(AbstractClientScanner.java:97)
    at com.purato.common.dao.hbase.HbaseQuery.execute(HbaseQuery.java:82)

Caused by: com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.IOExceptionWithStatus: Error in response stream
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResultQueueEntry.getResponseOrThrow(ResultQueueEntry.java:67)
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResponseQueueReader.getNextMergedRow(ResponseQueueReader.java:71)
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.StreamingBigtableResultScanner.next(StreamingBigtableResultScanner.java:64)
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.StreamingBigtableResultScanner.next(StreamingBigtableResultScanner.java:28)
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResumingStreamingResultScanner.next(ResumingStreamingResultScanner.java:93)
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResumingStreamingResultScanner.next(ResumingStreamingResultScanner.java:40)
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.BigtableResultScannerAdapter$1.next(BigtableResultScannerAdapter.java:43)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractClientScanner$1.hasNext(AbstractClientScanner.java:94)
        ... 39 more
Caused by: com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Row filter exceeds maximum size of 4096 bytes
        at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:431)
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableDataGrpcClient$5.onClose(BigtableDataGrpcClient.java:308)
        at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$3.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:453)
        at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:54)
        at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor$TaskRunner.run(SerializingExecutor.java:154)
        ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. I just checked; 4096 bytes is a system limit for Filter lengths.

You'll need to find a way to shorten your Filter, designed your query or look into post filtering on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Do you plan to update pages with quotas or limitation size in BigTable docs?